# How to remove one column header from the DOM element using Jquery based on data-index="9"

Tags: jquery

Please let me know how to remove the one column header which has the value `data-index="9"`, Please help me.

This is my DOM element -

```
<th class="k-header" id="c1572d8d-c80c-4a1b-891d-7efdfcbfb5d6" rowspan="1" scope="col" data-index="9">&nbsp;</th>
```

I want to delete this complete `<th>` element

I have tried this code, it did not work -

```
$('data-index[9]').remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
$("[data-index=9]").remove()
```

Square brackets are put around the entire attribute specification, with an operator like `=` separating the attribute name from the value you're testing it against.

See [jQuery Attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Your code is looking for an attribute like:

```
<data-index 9>
```

Comment: Should probably pair the attribute selector with the `.k-header` class to reduce scope.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me a lot